# Select2 not showing results, but successfully returning JSON

Tags: json, jquery-select2

I'm using the Select2 jQuery plugin with MVC4. I have my JavaScript file working with fetching data in JSON in my controller, but I'm getting an error when I debug and try to display the results:

```
Unable to get property 'toUpperCase' of undefined or null reference
```

I think it might have to do with the JSON I'm returning since it looks like objects or the fact that they're ints, but I'm not entirely sure. Converting them to strings via ToString() didn't work either. 
    [{"name":1,"label":1,},{"name":2,"label":2},...]

Here's my JS:

```
$("#ItemID").select2({
    ...
    ajax: {
    url: $("#ItemID").attr("data-getids"),
    dataType: "json",
    data: function (param) {
        return {query: param};},
    results: function(data) {
        return {results: data};}
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to print (param) and (data) to see what it takes; and check if your query is correct

Comment: searchterm is getting the correct value (the search query). Data is outputting [object Object],[object Object], etc. Which I have no idea is right or not.

Comment: Are you coding to JSON? the result in your url?

Comment: I was getting JSON back from the call. Unfortunately I'm on mobile and formatting is difficult to do, but I showed an example of what I was getting above the JS code. I ended up resolving my issue just recently though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm using an older version of select2 (3.4.5) and I ended up mapping the JSON in the results function.

```
results: function (data) {
    return {
        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
            return {text: item.name,
            id: item.id};
        };
    }),
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to retain the `id` property as well! Right now it won't be included, so your results won't be selectable.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me--I noticed this yesterday but I forgot to fix my answer.